# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined while fetching from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, array.prototype.map

I have been trying to make a simple API fetch but I can't understand what I'm doing wrong
I have read many questions but I really feel like I'm missing something since everything seems correct (it obviously isn't)

```
import { useState } from "react";
import ProductCard from "./ArticleCard/ProductCard.js";

export default function ProductsIndex() {
  const [searchText, set_searchText] = useState("");
  const [state, set_state] = useState({ status: "idle" });
  const search = async () => {
    if (searchText === "") {
      set_state({ status: "idle" });
      return;
    }
    set_state({ status: "searching" });
    const queryParam = encodeURIComponent(searchText);
    const data = await fetch(
      /* base browser fetch  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch*/
      `https://omdbapi.com/?apikey=6a06f383&s=${queryParam}`
    ).then((r) => r.json());
    set_state({ status: "done!", data: data.Search });
  };
  console.log(state.data);
  return (
    <div className="ProductsIndex">
      We sell movies for a high price.
      <h1>Discover some movies!</h1>
      <p>
        <input
          value={searchText}
          onChange={(e) => set_searchText(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button onClick={search}>Search</button>
      </p>{" "}
      <p>
        {state.data.map((movie) => (
          <ProductCard
            poster={movie.poster}
            title={movie.title}
            year={movie.year}
            type={movie.type}
          />
        ))}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The  console.log(state.data) gives the desired result, so it's as if the data isn't being passed down.. and I don't understand why

result from console.log(state.data):

```
[
    {
        "Title": "Finding Nemo",
        "Year": "2003",
        "imdbID": "tt0266543",
        "Type": "movie",
        "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZTAzNWZlNmUtZDEzYi00ZjA5LWIwYjEtZGM1NWE1MjE4YWRhXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNjU0OTQ0OTY@._V1_SX300.jpg"
    },
    {
        "Title": "Finding Nemo",
        "Year": "2003",
        "imdbID": "tt0401422",
        "Type": "game",
        "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNGEzMjdiZGEtYzU3ZC00OGFmLWI3NTgtZTcyNTFjYTliNDg5XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNjExODE1MDc@._V1_SX300.jpg"
    },
    {
        "Title": "Finding Nemo Submarine Voyage",
        "Year": "2007",
        "imdbID": "tt1319713",
        "Type": "movie",
        "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMzAxMzMyODQtNWY0Yy00N2M3LWE5MDQtZDUzNjc1ZGFmMzA4XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMzkxMzc4Mw@@._V1_SX300.jpg"
    },
    {
        "Title": "Finding Nemo: Studio Tour of Pixar",
        "Year": "2003",
        "imdbID": "tt1248974",
        "Type": "movie",
        "Poster": "N/A"
    },
    {
        "Title": "Finding Nemo: A Filmmakers' Roundtable",
        "Year": "2012",
        "imdbID": "tt10255922",
        "Type": "movie",
        "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNjAyMTBmODQtZGYxMC00NjdhLThhN2MtODlhMDI4NTczYTMyXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNDEyNjEzOTg@._V1_SX300.jpg"
    }
]
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just fixed up couple of things:

1. Define the sate for data

`const [state, set_state] = useState({ status: "idle",data:[] });`

2. Check your array before iterating

   ```
   {state.data && state.data.map((movie) => (
      <ProductCard
        poster={movie.poster}
        title={movie.title}
        year={movie.year}
        type={movie.type}
      />
    ))}
   ```

I have created a small demo: search nemo, press button and please check the console, https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-dubinsky-3bxsf?file=/src/App.js:155-219

Comment: Oh my that fixed it! Thank you so much!

I understand that we're checking the array before we interoplate it, but why is that a necessity? Is it because react is "faster" than the API and it prevents it from mapping an undefined?

thanks again

Comment: the first time when the component renders, the API is not hit, but it tries to iterate to the `state.data` which will be undefined. We need to stop that iteration when undefined. :)

Comment: That clears it, thanks a lot! upvoted everything :)

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize the `state.data`
Try like this.

```
 const [state, set_state] = useState({ status: "idle",data:[] });
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your answer! 

I implemented it but it doesn't work :( still same error at 
`{state.data.map((movie) => (`

Answer (score 1):

i think i got what the problem is!!!
When you set a new state, it replaces the previous one.
With that in mind, when you set your loading status like this:

```js
set_state({ status: "idle" });
```

it actually makes your `state.data` undefined, so, it throws the exception.

Instead of reassigning your entire state, try replacing only the things that need to be changed:

```js
set_state({ ...state, status: "idle" });
```

So, whenever tou call your set_state method, you should add your `...state`, so you won't have this problem.